# how can I handle push notification when my app is not running

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications, ios-3.x

how can I handle push notification when my app is not running
i am developing for ios3 .please help

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A short example:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    NSDictionary *tmpDic = [launchOptions objectForKey:@"UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey"];

    //if tmpDic is not nil, then your app is launched due to an APNs push, therefore check this NSDictionary for further information
    if (tmpDic != nil) {
        NSLog(@" - launch options dict has something ");
        NSLog(@" - badge number is %@ ", [[tmpDic objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"badge"]);
        NSLog(@" - ");
    }
```

Edited: About the NSDictionary you received, from Apple's official documentation:

> You can access the contents of the aps
>   dictionary—though you shouldn’t need
>   to in most cases—using the following
>   keys:
>
> 1. alert—The value may either be a string for the alert message or a
>      dictionary with two keys: body and
>      show-view. The value of the former is
>      the alert message and the latter is a
>      Boolean (false or true). If false, the
>      alert’s View button is not shown. The
>      default is to show the View button
>      which, if the user taps it, launches
>      the application.
> 2. badge—A number indicating the quantity of data items to download
>      from the provider. This number is to
>      be displayed on the application icon.
>      The absence of a badge property
>      indicates that any number currently
>      badging the icon should be removed.
> 3. sound—The name of a sound file in the application bundle to play as an
>      alert sound. If “default” is
>      specified, the default sound should be
>      played.
>
> The dictionary may also have
>   custom data defined by the provider
>   according to the JSON schema. The
>   properties for custom data should be
>   specified at the same level as the aps
>   dictionary. However, custom-defined
>   properties should not be used for mass
>   data transport because there is a
>   strict size limit per notification
>   (256 bytes) and delivery is not
>   guaranteed.

Comment: can you explore the NSDictionary when I am receiving notification

Comment: Its clients requirement that application should not open and it make call.is it possible?

Comment: If what you mean is that the user cancels the APNs AlertView, then your app won't be launched, and won't get notified about such a push. So no, it's not possible.

Comment: My making calls as I receive the notification,but it makes call after opening the launching the application,is it possible with out launching?

Comment: No, if the user accepts the APNs alert, the app will be launched. It's not up to you.